# Can I download all PDFs linked on a Page with Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, pdf, internet-explorer

I want to download all the pdf's that are linked on a web page. The site contains a long list with links to pdf files. As it is many and I want to download all of them I want to download them all at once. As this is at work and I cant install another Browser I will have to use Internet Explorer. I'm not sure if an add-on to Internet Explorer would work. So the best would be something to do this natively in the browser without clicking each link.

Comment: Check this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7f60.w.html this may get you with some idea but not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please tell us what you have researched and already attempted to resolve this. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: @vembutech This is not what I'm looking for I want to download the linked pdf files. So the files are already in a pdf format.

Comment: @CharlieRB What I have done so far is right click on each link and download it manualy. I have also googled and haven't found anything.

Comment: Some solution like this would be nice but preferably no addon:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master/mcceagdollnkjlogmdckgjakjapmkdjf

Comment: Install a web grabber. I use pavuk but it's not WIndows based. httrack looks to be for windows and workable.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have permission to install programs for security reasons... The page is also a intranet page... Maybe add ons will work... got to try... Best would be some built in functionality or script I can execute in the browser console.

Comment: Many programs don't need to be "installed" in the traditional sense. You just download and open them. If you can't download and open something, it's likely you won't be able to open the add-on.

Comment: It would also be nice to know what version of IE and Windows you are using. I'm thinking you are out of luck if you can't add anything. Most of the "off line" features have been removed from IE for security reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an issue that should be resolved with your IT department.